# The meaning of 立派だよ

Tags: meaning, word-choice

If I say:

> お前は立派だよ

I tell the person that they are amazing as a person or that they did an amazing job?

Answer (score 3):

The adjective can be applied to both works and to people. Your example sentence has no further context, so we can only assume you are talking about the person.

Answer (score 2):

立派 is generally used in the literal sense as a positive thing, either complimenting someone or describing something in a good way.

I have also heard it used in a somewhat sarcastic or euphemistic way, such as 立派なおなか to describe a bulging (fat) stomach. With your example, 立派 is being applied to the person. But without further context, it's not easy to give a proper translation.